# Querying polymorphic table and related tables for records

Tags: laravel

Hi I have an activities table which holds records for Reply and Thread posted. I'm trying to query the activities table to reach the Reply and Thread tables for a search to return records but I'm having trouble understanding why my query is not working.

Here is what I have:

```
$results = \DB::table('activities')
        ->join('threads', function($builder) use ($search) {
            $builder->on('threads.id', '=', 'activities.activity_id')
            ->where('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');

        })
        ->join('replies', function($builder) {
            $builder->on('replies.id', '=', 'activities.activity_id');

        })
        ->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->get();
```

Can anybody please help me?

Thank you.

```
"select * from `activities` inner join `threads` on `threads`.`id` = `activities`.`activity_id` and `activities`.`activity_type` = ? inner join `replies` on `replies`.`id` = `activities`.`activity_id` and `activities`.`activity_type` = ? where `replies`.`body` LIKE ? or `threads`.`title` LIKE ? or `threads`.`body` LIKE ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in polymorph relation you have two columns to hold the relation information, in this case there must be `'activities.activity_id','activities.activity_type'`.

you should include the second column in join statement:

```
 $results = \DB::table('activities')
            ->leftJoin('threads', function($builder) {
                $builder->on('threads.id', '=', 'activities.activity_id')
                ->where('activities.activity_type',Thread::class);

        })
        ->leftJoin('replies', function($builder) {
            $builder->on('replies.id', '=', 'activities.activity_id')
            ->where('activities.activity_type',Reply::class);
        })
        ->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->get();
```

and you can do it this way:

in your Activity Model add this relations:

```
  public function thread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class,'activity_id')
            ->where('activity_type',Thread::class);
    }

public function replay()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Replay::class,'activity_id')
        ->where('activity_type',Replay::class);
}
```

now you can use normal whereHas like this:

```
  $results = Activity::with('activityable')->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        })->orWhereHas('replay', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');

        })->get();
```

note that im not sure of the polymorphic relation name in your Activity model,
replace the relation name 'activityable' with the actually name in your model.

Comment: Thank you sir for responding with a possible solution. However my query still returns with no results.

Comment: It would be great to see what query is built using laravel eloquent. For that you can use `toSql` method at place of  `get`. Once you know what is the issue with query, you can tweak your eloquent and get the correct one.

Comment: I think in my case, I cannot query the activities table because it is polymorph and doesn't hold the records that I want, is this true? I've included the query in the body now.

Comment: could you share your models?

Comment: you can definitely query the model, but if no record found for a given search then it should be empty array

Comment: @user123 you should be sure of the search results existence  to test your code

Comment: @OMR, you're quite good at laravel, hope will learn from you. Couldn't resist a voteup for the same.

Comment: public function activity()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Activity::class, 'activity');
    } -- is this is a good example of the model?

Comment: I do know it exists but it will not return any results.

Comment: please try using leftJoin as the answer has been updated

Comment: Thank you. I have just tried it, but it does not work.

Comment: try searching manually using mysql query in database itself, so you can verify whether results are correct or not

Comment: I got no results from the query but I will try as @JitendraYadav has suggested thanks for your suggestion I hadn't thought of this.

Comment: I think I may just have the wrong query, because it still is returning no results, I want to query from the Activities but get the Thread body and Reply body, is that possible? This was my query:: select * from activities inner join threads on threads.id = activities.activity_id and activities.activity_type = 'App\Thread' inner join replies on replies.id = activities.activity_id and activities.activity_type = 'App\Reply' where replies.body LIKE 'illum' or threads.title LIKE 'illum' or threads.body LIKE 'illum'

Comment: you can't use innerJoin, try leftJoin

Comment: Thank you, I have also tried left join with no results:: select * from activities left join threads on threads.id = activities.activity_id and activities.activity_type = 'App\Thread' left join replies on replies.id = activities.activity_id and activities.activity_type = 'App\Reply' where replies.body LIKE 'illum' or threads.title LIKE 'illum' or threads.body LIKE 'illum'

Comment: Edited: select * from activities left join threads on threads.id = activities.activity_id and activities.activity_type = 'App\Thread' left join replies on replies.id = activities.activity_id and activities.activity_type = 'App\Reply' where replies.body LIKE '%illum%' or threads.title like '%illum%' or threads.body LIKE '%illum%'

Comment: I have tried your most updated code sir but it still is not returning any results.