# Query for returning individual records from related table in a polymorphic relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm currently working with an Activities table which has Thread and Replies records associated with it. When I try to join the tables, I get a mix and match and both records and it doesn't return individual records, but with records containing both Thread and Reply "body" field. I'm hoping someone can see what I'm trying to do with the code I'm providing:

```
if (request('name')){
    $name = request('name');
    $user = User::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
    $activities = \DB::table('activities')
    ->leftJoin('threads', function($builder) use ($user){
        $builder->on('threads.user_id', '=', 'activities.user_id')
        ->where('activities.user_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->where('activities.activity_type', '=', 'App\Thread');
    })
    ->leftJoin('replies', function($builder) use ($user){
        $builder->on('replies.user_id', '=', 'activities.user_id')
        ->where('activities.user_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->where('activities.activity_type', '=', 'App\Reply');
    })
    ->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->orWhere('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->get()->unique('id');
}
```

I want to return Threads and Replies separately with all the other fields, as sometimes in my experimentation it has led to the user being null or the body being null and I just don't understand why.

Sometimes it will return a App\Thread in the Activities table that I have created as an App\Reply. I'll admit my knowledge of joins is limited so I'm asking if anyone can please help!

I've got this new query here:

```
    $activities = Activity::with('activity')->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
        $query->where('threads.user_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->where('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            
    })->orWhereHas('reply', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
        $query->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('replies.user_id', '=', $user->id);

    })->get();
```

Thank you!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: hi @user123, have you tried the second way provider in my answer using Model relations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64112322/10573560

Comment: Thanks I have tried it, and it worked, but I think this is a new problem, when I add user into the mix all the models are intertwined.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to include the user in the query builder, I just added the user after my ::with clause and got the following query to work:

```
    $activities = Activity::with('activity')->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
        $query->where('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            
    })->orWhereHas('reply', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
        $query->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('replies.user_id', '=', $user->id);

    })->get();
```

Anyone in the future who may need some additional assistance can visit this link: https://zaengle.com/blog/using-wherehas-in-laravel-polymorphic-relations